# Magento: category display wrong order

Tags: magento, navigation, categories

I used magento 1.6.2, I found there were some problems in displaying category in navigation.
1. I have exchanged the positions of two categories. The category A and B are categories, C is the child of B. I exchanged the postion of A and C in admin page. So A is the child of B now, And I also checked the table of catalog_category_entity, it shows that A'parent is B. But I still find the positons of them in front page do not changed. I have deleted cache and ssl.
Another problem is added new category does not show on navigation, I have checked:
isActive is yes, Include in Navigation Menu is yes. But it is useless.

Who know about this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your website/store scope in the categories page in admin panel

Also try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thanks Shair. But it is useless. and I find when I remove our online shop in localhost. It works fine. But I still can not fix it on our server. It should not be a problem of magento, but might apache, memory problem etc.. I am confusing.......

Comment: And I also find the order of categories in navigation are as same as bofore I modified. But I have refreshed caches in backend and deleted all in var/cache and var/session. I think there should be some place to save those old setting.                                                            Any advice?

Comment: Try making a new installation of magento on your server and importing your database to it.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was caused by not reindexing index management.

Comment: What was the fix? Ive read up on [this link](http://www.novusweb.com/1622/e-commerce-technology/fixing-magento-category-order-problems/), was it that?

Comment: What actually is the problem that you are facing? What do you want to achieve? The solution to PhilipSong's problem was that he reindexed the data. You can do this by going to the Admin panel and browsing to **System->Index Management**